# Location Tracking as Evidence

Tags: gps, gps-tracking

With location tracking enabled in Android, I see entries in "Your Timeline" in Google Maps. I know it's possible to add/remove/edit entries in this timeline, but is there are a way to get a reliable, unmodified export of what has been tracked that could be used as evidence? I understand that tracking and times might not be 100% but I essentially want to see if there's a way to get a version similar to the KML export that hasn't been edited that I could say "this export can't be edited".

I've been told the red dots that appear on the map can't be edited and can be relied on but I'm not so sure if there's any non-editable version of Android's tracking history?

Answer (score 0):

All personal data in your Google account, including timeline data, can be exported. here's an article showing how to do it.
https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-download-your-personal-data-from-google/

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't ask how to do it (I showed how I could do it in my question), but I want to know if there's a way to download said data *without it being modified* by any changes made via the gui.

Comment: Sorry, yes, misunderstood. I don't know but I think it's unlikely. If I deliberately removed removed an item from my timeline and somehow Google still retained it (in history or wherever) it would make a nonsense of being able to download everything Google holds on you. In my jurisdiction at least that would not satisfy  Google's legal responsibility.